# Erro react-native run-android

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, react-native

Fiz a instalação do *react-native-cli*, *android* *sdk* e o emulador do *android*. Consegui fazer o *init* do projeto mas quando rodo o comando *react-native run-android* ele mostra o log:

> Scanning 577 folders for symlinks in D:\dev\git-repo\cursos\reactNative\InstaluraMobile\node_modules (23ms)<>
>   JS server already running.
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>   Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>       set up your Android development environment:
>       https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html`

Answer (score 2):

Antes de rodar o comando `react-native run-android`, você precisa ter o emulador do Android rodando com o AVD (Android Video Device).

Uma das maneiras de rodar o emulador é abrindo o projeto no Android Studio e:

(1) clicando `Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager`
 *(Ferramentas -> Android -> Gerenciador de AVD)*

(2) clique o botão (verde) de play para rodar o emulador com o AVD desejado (escolha um da lista; se não tiver nenhum, crie um)

Depois de ter o emulador já aberto e rodando o sistema Android, execute o comando `react-native run-android` para poder abrir o servidor de desenvolvimento e conectar-se ao emulador.

---

Voce tem que rodar o comando do diretorio principal do projeto. Isto é, se voce gerou o projeto assim: `react-native init MeuProjeto`, não esqueça de mudar para o diretório do projeto antes de iniciar tudo:

```
cd MeuProjeto
react-native run-android
```